# Cannot update php.ini in Mac OS Lion

Tags: php

Something is very wrong in my php/apache setup in Mac OS Lion.

If I change `/private/etc/php.ini` then I do `sudo apachectl -k restart`, the changes are not reflected.

After I do `sudo apachectl -k stop`, I can still connect to `localhost` in browser, and my php runs as usual.

I've even tried emptying `/private/etc/php.ini` and restart the apache server, but still nothing happened.

In phpinfo, value of Loaded Configuration File is `/private/etc/php.ini`

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Sounds, that you have another MAMP-stack installed somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

if you have MAMP then just change the php.ini file in the MAMP folder with the php version you use.

If not then, try the /etc/php.ini with a sudo vim command. You won't be able to make the changes if you don't access the ini as sudo.

That was my problem earlier when I was trying to get xdebug working, I had to edit the php as super user.